# Neural Network to identify Seven-Segment Numerals

Tags: neural-network, computer-science

I am studying machine learning and I am working on my first neural network as a project for one of my classes. I am programming the network in java. The point of the network is to identify seven-segmented numeral (like on a regular digital clock). The network does not actually have to be linked to any real sensors, it just needs to work in theory based on inputs as 0's and 1's in text form, not binary, which correspond to a hypothetical sensor matrix laid across the top of the number.

My question is, what sort of output am I looking to get?

1. Will the binary output be just correspond to the same sort of matrix as input or is the binary output supposed to represent the input number in binary such as returning 111 for 7?
2. If it does just return another matrix, what is the point of the network?

Answer (score 0):

The input for a seven-segment numeral would be a (1 X 7) vector, with 1 for segments that are on and 0 for segments that are off.

As for the output, you don't specify what you want it to be, so let's assume you want it to tell you "which digit is the screen showing". Since there are 10 digits (0 through 9), you have 10 possible answers. The output would be a (1 X 10) vector, with each number corresponding to one of the digits. Its value represents how confident the network is that this is the correct answer (typically the output values lie in [0, 1], but it depends on your setup)  Ideally you would want the network to return a vector having 1 on one attribute and zeros in all others.

Note however, that this case a classifier is not useful. A classification algorithm generalizes what it has seen in the past. So, it would be useful for handwritten recognition, because even if the same person writes the same digit twice, it is not exactly the same. In your case, each digit is the same across all the 7-segment displays, so you network is not exactly learning, rather memorizing the input.

Comment: Okay I suspected that was the case so for an output representing 1 I'm looking for something like this:

    m->   
n  001
 |  001
V  001

So if my my input comes in this same form, what is the advantage of a neural network if it just returns the inputs as outputs? I understand that what I'm doing is an extremely simplified version of a net, this is of course for educational purposes only. Isn't all of the recognition done by the sensor and perhaps some simply processing though?